# Controlling how QtWebKit resizes images

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt4

```
<img width='500' height='500' src='image.png'>
```

image.png is larger than 500x500 so when I display it webkit automatically resizes it.
The problem is the quality is very poor.

My guess is it uses a nearest-neighbor algorithm or something similar and so the result leaves much to be desired.

Is it possible to make it use bicubic instead as image quality is significantly more important than speed in this case.

In contrast chrome is much better at resizing images so I'm guess it also uses webkit.

Note that I'm using a QWebView widget and PyQt, and example code in python is prefered as I'm not a c++ programmer so its hard for me to translate c++ to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPainter

yourQWebView.setRenderHints(QPainter.TextAntialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
```

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#renderHints-prop

Comment: Thank you, it has improved significantly. But chrome is still better, I'm gonna assume they are using custom resizing code outside what webkit provides.